# Manjaro linux неправильная настройка клавиатуры?

Tags: linux, клавиатура, kde, manjaro

Есть ноутбук (нетбук) Acer Aspire ES-11 (ES1-132-C4V3) с Manjaro и kde plasma.

Проблема в следующем - есть две раскладки - русская и английская. Та, которая не стоить по-умолчанию (любая из этих двух) - не распознает часть клавиш - т.к считает их стрелками numpud - как перевести их в режим символов ?

Т.е одна клавиша может работать в трех режимах : как символ, как цифра (при зажатом Fn+NumLk) и как стрелка numpud-а. Так вот, часть клавиш, как показывает перехват виртуальной клавиатурой - распознается как стрелки или как цифры с зажатым NumLk. Пытался менять модель клавиатуры в настройках - не помогло. Причем, если я ставлю по умолчанию - русскую раскладку -на русском - все клавиши начинают отрабатывать корректно, и с английским - так же. - т.е "ломается" вторая - противоположная раскладка.

Кто-то с таким сталкивался?

Comment: Так отожмите NumLock.

Comment: Если я отжимаю NumLock - клавиши начинают работать в режиме стрелок.